# Returning SelectListItem from DAL or Domain or equivalent

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, data-access-layer, listitem

If my requirement was to return data for a DropDownlist in a webform, a winform, a wpf form etc from a separate dll (DAL, Domain etc). What would you return?

I could use:

```
SelectListItem[]

Ilist<SelectListItem>

IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

and the others of a similar nature but I dont like the way 'SelectListItem' is tied to the System.Web.Mvc namespace. Maybe its just me but it just seems a little specific. My webform may not even be using MVC although it would still work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have sort of answered your own question in that it is inappropriate to return a SelectList from an assembly that may be consumed by applications that are not asp.net MVC. This would even lead to a WPF application have to reference System.Web.Mvc.

A more appropriate architecture would be to return an IEnumerable of some type that you will then convert to the appropriate list item type for the current application type. This conversion could occur in some sort of adapter layer or via extension methods if that is more helpful to you.

Comment: Yes that is my question really how are others doing it. How you have described is how I do it but all that conversion isnt required when a SelectListItem is returned of some type. I can just do DropDL.Foo = Repository.SomeListdata instead of havng to convert all the time. I actually return IEnumerable<Foo> then convert but again Im just trying o get other ideas

Comment: @William So therefore your best bet is then to have a FooDropDownService in your application that gets your list of Foo from the datastore and converts to the DropDownList type of you application.

Comment: That would mean the a service would have to be created for each app type ( Generally speaking my service is in the same dll as the repository and is used by all) I suppose you could create your own FooSelectListItem Class to be returned by the service and decouple from the MVC dll

Comment: After debating with myself lol I think your way is probably best. Just return a list of table data from the Repository : Service : Into Apps own service to convert into ListItem : into Dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem and my solution was to create a tiny class in the services layer and map the data to `SelectListItem`s in the view. Example code:

1) Surrogate class in the services layer:

```
public class SelectListItemBase
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

2) The view model:

```
public class FetchWordsIntegrationViewModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItemBase> WordTypes { get; private set; }

    public FetchWordsIntegrationViewModel()
    {
        WordTypes = new List<SelectListItemBase>();

        WordTypes.Add(new SelectListItemBase() { Value = "0", Text = Constants.Ids.SelectionListDefaultText });
        WordTypes.Add(new SelectListItemBase() { Value = ((int)FetchedWordType.ProperNoun).ToString(), Text = "Proper noun" });
        // other select list items here
    }
}
```

3) Code in the action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = theService.CreateViewModel();
    return View(vm);
}
```

4) Mapping using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) (this is not required as `SelectListItem`s can easily be generated using LINQ)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SelectListItemBase, SelectListItem>();
```

5) Finally, code from the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WordTypes,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Mapper.Map(
        Model.WordTypes, 
        typeof(IList<SelectListItemBase>), 
        typeof(IList<SelectListItem>))
)
```

It is quite convoluted for this simple task, but allows desired decoupling and also allows to easy map other properties, if needed.